# how to target nested expression/function jquery?

Tags: jquery, function, nested

I have the following nested function like this:

```
var initApp = (function(app) {

app.testOne = function () {

    if (conditions === true) {
        testTwo();
    }
    console.log("test 1 fired");

    var testTwo = function () {
        console.log("test 2");
    }
}
return app; })({});
```

I can use "initApp.testOne()" to call testOne but how do I call testTwo() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to call testTwo before it is declared:

```
var initApp = (function (app) {

    app.testOne = function () {

        var testTwo = function () {
            console.log("test 2");
        }
        if (conditions === true) {
            testTwo();
        }
        console.log("test 1 fired");

    }
    return app;
})({});
```

Comment: how do I target this from the root? e.g

initApp.testOne.testTwo();